# I changed a button background to an image, and removed the width/height constraints, now the button disappeared on build

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I changed a button from text/background to an image. I then removed the width and height constraints because I read it should intrinsically resize itself and now the button won't show after I run a build! How do I fix this?

This is in xcode using Swift.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout on other views in your xib?  even with the image you should keep your width/height constraints just in case you swap out the image you don't want your button changing size

Comment: Ah ok. I'll add the constraints back in. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: By the way @mattyayoh would you consider that a best or standard practice?

Comment: Standard, based off my work and looking at other's.  Best because you ensure it is always the size you expect it to be.  Keep in mind you probably will want to ensure the size is dynamic based off of screen size, as well